# How to cross-compile curl on macosx to suport MAC catalyst Apple silicon?

Tags: curl, cross-compiling, catalyst, apple-silicon

**catalyst + x86_64 to support intel script as below:**

```
export CFLAGS="-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi -arch x86_64 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min="10.15" -fembed-bitcode -Werror=partial-availability"
export CXXFLAGS="-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi"
export LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

./configure --disable-shared --enable-ipv6 --enable-static --enable-threaded-resolver --prefix=${PREFIX} && make -j8 && make install

***catalyst + arm64  to support Apple Silicon ？***